Unity/Photon: How to have a network prefab appear differently for each client
I'm trying to build a game where players in a room can view each other differently depending on their relationships. I.E: player A, B, and C are in a room. A and B are friends so they can see each other's true avatar, while on player C's client he can only see the blank "default avatar" of A and B.
I've been reading Photon documentations and couldn't find anything useful. I genuinely have no clue how to implement this. My best idea so far is to locally spawn the correct avatar on C's client, while still having it being controled by A and B by using some finicky service to manually sync their rotation/position.
Can someone point me the in the right direction. Let me know if I'm missing something. Thank you!
